# Matching 2 JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a very large json like :

```
raw_obj= {"001" : {....}, "002" : {....}};
```

and I have an another json object which is just returned from server :

```
search_result = {["001", "005", "123"]};
```

I want to do something like

```
$.each(search_result, function(i,val){
 alert(raw_obj.search_result[i]);
});
```

Is it possible? I don't want to loop through those 2 objects because in practical, there will be have around 2000 elements in a "raw_json". Which means the worst case is 2000x2000 times loop per one query.

Comment: *How* do you want to match the two objects? What's the criteria for a match?

Comment: `{["001"], ["005"], ["123"]}` what is *that*? Are you sure this is returned from server?

Comment: search_result is not a valid object.

Comment: Your `search_result` is an invalid object...Javascript doesn't intrepret properly.

Comment: Would you please explain better what you want? there could be many ways to solve your problem.

Comment: So actually your problem is not related to JSON at all but to how to manage JS objects efficiently?

Comment: Sorry. It suppose to be {["001", "002", "123"]} in "search_result"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var raw_obj= {"001" : {'...'}, "002" : {'...'}};
var search_results = ["001", "005", "123"];    // just an array

$.each(search_results, function(i, result) {
    alert(raw_obj[result]);
});
```

The search results are an array (ie, list), not an object (ie, map) and so the syntax should be modified as above.  If you have no control over the server response, use string parsing to build a new array.